# Change 550 Mail to noreply has been suspended for Exim

Tags: email, exim

- List item

Someone replied to a noreply email address and received the following response:

> Change 550 Mail to noreply@domain.tld has been suspended

The footer of *all* outgoing emails from that account specify to *not* reply to that account.

What file(s) do I have to edit (and their typical path/location on the server) in order to change and customize the response for the people who can't read emails with the overwhelming number of three sentences?

---

The file at `/etc/exim.conf` contains the following lines:

```
  # implemented for "suspend incoming email" feature
  deny
       domains = +local_domains
       condition = ${if exists {${extract{5}{::}{${lookup passwd{${lookup{$domain}lsearch{/etc/userdomains}{$value}}}{$value}}}}/etc/\.$local_part\@$domain\.suspended_incoming}}
       message = Mail to ${lc:$local_part@$domain} has been suspended
       log_message = Mail to ${lc:$local_part@$domain} has been suspended

  # implemented for "suspend outgoing email" feature for domains and individual webmail/pop accounts
  deny
    domains = ! +local_domains
    condition = ${perl{check_outgoing_mail_suspended}}
    message = ${perl{get_outgoing_mail_suspended_message}}
    log_message = ${perl{get_outgoing_mail_suspended_message}}
```

I adjust them with some basic tests and neither `message` nor `log_message` were adjusted when replying to the suspended account. Perhaps either the response is cached in memory or this is a legacy definition that has been superseded by another configuration?

Comment: What is your mail server?

Comment: You should simply discard responses to "noreply", and change the footer to say so.

Comment: @RomeoNinov Exim.

Answer (score 0):

To put mails to `noreply` address you can use **:blackhole:** definition:
in `/etc/aliases` add

```
noreply: :blackhole:
```

For more information you can check [here](https://www.electrictoolbox.com/exim4-discard-mail-blackhole/)

Comment: Two questions:
1.) Where in that configuration file would I put that?
2.) How can I set a custom message if the account (NOT the domain) is a "noreply" (not "noreply@domain.tld)?

Comment: @John, as mentioned in answer the file is `/etc/aliases`. About custom message its different question. Please create new question